# Converting JQuery command to simple JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is the command in JQuery:

```
  $("li.info-item div.body h3.name a[href*="infor"]")
```

and I would like it to make it in JS. I tried this:

```
 document.querySelector("li.infor-item div.body h3.name a[href*="infor"]")
```

and the error is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list(…)
```

Comment: Missing `+` before and after infor.

Comment: `"infor"` uses `"` quotes inside a string quoted with `"` quotes.. either change one of them, or, if `infor` is a variable, use `+` to concatenate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using double quotes inside double quotes try using single quotes and use querySelectorAll instead of querySelector to get all matching elements.

```
document.querySelectorAll('li.infor-item div.body h3.name a[href*="infor"]')
```

Comment: in need it needs single quotes. But the result is not the same as the JQuery. I mean using the JQuery command I receive many result and this is what I expect. But using the JS commnad I receive only the first

Comment: @Berbery use `querySelectorAll` instead.